# How to clone a double linked list using recursivity

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, clone, nodes

Im trying to implement a method which clones a double linked list. I'm trying to do it recursivity as it's a requirement.

I think that it clones right but when I'm trying to add another element to the end of list, it's added to the original queue and not to the cloned.

this is the main where I call the methods and I do the clone:

```
    doublelinkedlist<Integer> aux=new doublelinkedlist<Integer>();
    doublelinkedlist<Integer> aux2=new doublelinkedlist<Integer>();
    aux.addRight(10);
    aux.addRight(11);
    aux.addRight(9);
    aux.addRight(12);
    //aux2.addRight(12);
    aux2 = (doublelinkedlist<Integer>) aux.clone();
    aux2.RemoveRight();
    System.out.println("Original Queue: "+aux.toString());
    System.out.println("Copy queue: "+aux2.toString());
```

This is the clone method of DoubleLinkedList:

```
public Object clone(){
    doublelinkedlist copia = null;
    try{
        copia = (doublelinkedlist)super.clone();

        if (left != null){
            copia.left = (node<E>)left.clone();
        }
    }catch (CloneNotSupportedException e){
        return null;
    }
    return copia;
}
```

and this is the clone of node class:

```
    public Object clone(){
        node<E> copia = null;
        try{
            copia = (node<E>)(super.clone());

            if (next != null){
                copia.next = (node<E>)(next.clone());
                copia.prev = copia;
            }

        }catch (CloneNotSupportedException e){
            return null;
        }
        return copia;
    }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.copy(dest, src);` to clone the list.
Here is an example of clone with recursivity

```
public class ClonableLinkedList extends LinkedList<Double> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClonableLinkedList clonable = new ClonableLinkedList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            clonable.add(new Random().nextDouble());
        }
        LinkedList<Double> cloned = clonable.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("List1 = %f, List2 = %f", clonable.get(i), cloned.get(i)));
        }
    }

    public LinkedList<Double> clone() {
        LinkedList<Double> list = new LinkedList<Double>();
        return cloneElements(list, 0);
    }

    private LinkedList<Double> cloneElements(LinkedList<Double> list, int index) {
        list.add(this.get(index++));
        if (index < this.size()) {
            return cloneElements(list, index);
        } else {
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should implement the clone method if so I would have done this but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the following line:

```
copia = (doublelinkedlist)super.clone();
```

From the [JavaDocs of Object#clone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--)

> By convention, the object returned by this method should be
>   independent of this object (which is being cloned). To achieve this
>   independence, it may be necessary to modify one or more fields of the
>   object returned by super.clone before returning it.

*Now comes the important part:*

> Typically, this
>   means copying any mutable objects that comprise the internal "deep
>   structure" of the object being cloned and replacing the references to
>   these objects with references to the copies. 
>   
>   [...] 
>   Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a 
>   "deep copy" operation.

You aren't deep-copying your objects, you get just a new reference to them.

Comment: I dont really understand, in my case, what should I write to do a deep copy?